# Unexpected token if

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Вчера начала учить react. Столкнулась с ошибкой, но не понимаю её, посмотрела документацию - if как if, вроде, всё корректно.

> babel.min.js Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected
>   token if

Код

```
render() {
    return (
      if(this.state.signIn){
        return this.rendSignIn ();
      }
      else{
        return this.rendSignUp ();
      }
    );
  };
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, из-за чего возникает ошибка и как её исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нельзя делать `return` ... `return` в любом случае
2. В `return` нельзя использовать условный оператор `if`, только
   тернарный `?`

Comment: Это актуально только для js?

Comment: @Yiulia да вроде как для всех языков

Answer (score 2):

Конструкция return {} возвращает литерал объёкта, и по этой причине ошибка  `Unexpected token if`, так как в литералах объектов конструкции `if ... else` недопустимы :)

Корректная конструкция в вашем случае была бы:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.signIn){
        return this.rendSignIn ();
    } else {
        return this.rendSignUp ();
    }
};
```